# Loading a JSON file trough an angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to call an Angular service function "getDecks()" from a controller "menuBarCtrl". I want to store the content of the file in a local $scope variable after getDecks() returns the content of my JSON file.

However, I only get an 'undefined' if I try to display that value in the console.

```js
ajapp.controller('MenuBarCtrl', function($scope, $http, CardProvider) {

    $scope.decks = CardProvider.getDecks();

    console.log($scope.decks);

});

ajapp.service('CardProvider', function($http) {

    this.getDecks = function(){

        var json;
        $http.get('content/SetList.json').success(function(data, status){

            json = data;
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            alert("File Request Failed ["+status+"]");
        });

        return json;
    }
});
```

Comment: try `return ` statement inside the `$http.get` function.

Comment: Do you know how promises work...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem's not angular but JS asynchronicity.

This seems to be what you're trying to achieve:

```
ajapp.controller('MenuBarCtrl', function($scope, $http, CardProvider) {
    CardProvider.getDecks()
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.decks = data;
    })
    .catch(function (data, status) {
        /* handle error*/
    });
});

ajapp.service('CardProvider', function($http) {
    this.getDecks = function(){
        return $http.get('content/SetList.json');
    }
});
```